# Latex: how break a line when summing over two things

Tags: latex

Lets say I want to sum over `i \in S` and `i \in T`. Currently I use:

```
\displaystyle \sum_{i \in S, i \in T} i
```

But this will display the sum-overs one **after** the other and not one **above** the other like I want.

How can I do this?

thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about LaTeX

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't understand the formula you are trying to typeset, but maybe this is what you want?

```
\sum_{i \in S \atop i \in T} i
```

Answer (score 27):

`\atop` doesn't give the right spacing.  You should use `amsmath` and use `\substack`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i \in S \atop i \in T} i
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sum_{\substack{i \in S\\ i \in T}} i
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The results, first with `\atop` on the left and `\substack` on the right:

[limits using atop http://www.astro.virginia.edu/~as8ca/SO/atop.png](http://www.astro.virginia.edu/~as8ca/SO/atop.png)
[limits using substack http://www.astro.virginia.edu/~as8ca/SO/substack.png](http://www.astro.virginia.edu/~as8ca/SO/substack.png)

And then one above the other, first `\atop`:

[limits using atop http://www.astro.virginia.edu/~as8ca/SO/atop.png](http://www.astro.virginia.edu/~as8ca/SO/atop.png)

then `\substack`:

[limits using substack http://www.astro.virginia.edu/~as8ca/SO/substack.png](http://www.astro.virginia.edu/~as8ca/SO/substack.png)

Comment: I'm trying to use substack, and it works fine, apart from one thing: when one of the terms in the substack is long (much longer than $i \in S$), then there is a long white space between the sum symbol and the term that is being summed up ($i$ in the example above). This white space corresponds to the width of the substack... How can I solve it so that it takes less space?

Comment: @pms You should ask that as a new question, and probably best over at http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Using the amsmath macros is good semantically, but I prefer the spacing with \atop.